# Using format() in R to convert numeric value to scientific notation after rounding

Tags: r, format, decimal, rounding, scientific-notation

A small snippet of my overall code is to round a given vector to a specified number of decimal places. The rounded value is then converted to standard notation, e.g. "1.2e-01".

The following does the rounding which works fine.

```r
values <- c(0.1234, 0.5678)
dig <- 2
rounded_vals <- round(values, dig) %>% str_trim()
```

When I run the following code I expect to see the same output for both lines.

```r
format(rounded_vals, scientific = TRUE)
format(c(0.12, 0.56), scientific = TRUE)
```

What I actually get is:

```r
> format(rounded_vals, scientific = TRUE)
[1] "0.12" "0.57"
> format(c(0.12, 0.56), scientific = TRUE)
[1] "1.2e-01" "5.6e-01"
```

Why doesn't `format(rounded_vals, scientific = TRUE)` return the same output and how can I adjust the code to do so?

Would appreciate any input :)

Edit: I missed out a bit of code that was causing the problem - seems to be that str_trim() covnerts to character.

Comment: Hi Karima! I run the code you wrote and It worked for me. I got `"1.2e-01" "5.7e-01"` Can you restart R and run it again?

Comment: Probably your `format()` is masked from an "ingenious" package. You could try `base::format(.)` or alternatively use `formatC(rounded_vals, format='e', digits=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `rounded_vals` might have been stored as character values. Try converting them to numbers using `as.numeric()` and then put it into the `format()` function.